# What ways are there to execute a SQLiteDatabase join function

Tags: android, sqlite, join

I need to use a join function in for the use of my android 'game'. I know how to write a inner- and outerjoin. What I need to know is what ways are there to execute a SQLiteDatabase join function?

You got the basic rawQuery where I can use the join, but I wonder if there is any other way like the select(query), insert, update and delete methodes which are implemented in the SQLiteDatabase class.
I just want confirmation if I'm not missing something at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no function exclusively to 'join' two tables. You will either run a `rawQuery` or `Query` to achieve the same.[Check with the documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

I would suggest to go with rawQuery.

Comment: Allright, thank you! :D
it's too bad though, would make it much easier